# C# using Linq in Queryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm a bit new to Linq and hoping someone could help me on something I'm currently strugling.

I currently have 2 list

```
public IQueryable<TRole> Roles
{
   get
   {
      var roles = new List<TRole>();
      roles.Add(CreateIdentityRole("Chairman", "Voorzitter"));
      roles.Add(CreateIdentityRole("Treasurer", "Penningmeester"));
      roles.Add(CreateIdentityRole("Ranking Responsible", "Rankingverantwoordelijke"));
                roles.Add(CreateIdentityRole("Competition Responsible", "Competitieverantwoordelijke"));
      roles.Add(CreateIdentityRole("Webmaster", "Webbeheerder"));
      roles.Add(CreateIdentityRole("Secretary", "Secretaris"));
      foreach(TRole role in roles)
      {
         if (!_roles.Contains(role))
            _roles.Add(role);
      }

      return _roles.AsQueryable<TRole>();
   }
}

private TRole CreateIdentityRole(string id, string name)
{
   TRole role = (TRole)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TRole));
   role.Id = id;
   role.Name = name;
   return role;
}

public void InitializePrivacy(IdentityUser user)
{
   var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
   var roleManager = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>();
   var roles = roleManager.Roles;
   List<string> userRoles = manager.GetRoles(user.Id);
}
```

right now I want to use Linq to get all roles which are not found in userRoles. Because the roles is a Queryable I do not really now how to achieve such result.

Comment: `Queryable` is a static class which provides methods for `IQueryable` implementations. You can't create an instance of it.

Comment: the Querable is achieved in another function. This is made to have an example of what I need to achieve. I adapted my script to show you where its created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IEnumerable interface. If your method return Querable result it will work. Try this:

```
IEnumerable<string> roles = roleManager.Roles;
List<string> userRoles = GetRoles(user.Id);

var result = roles.Except(userRoles);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `.Except()` should probably be enough:

```
using System.Linq;
//...
var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();
List<string> userRoles = manager.GetRoles(user.Id);
var ununsedRoles = roles.Execpt(userRoles);
```

This will give you all items roles, except those in `userRoles`.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

To get a collection of Roles that are not found in `userRoles`:

```
var rolesNotFound = roleManager.Roles
                      .Where(r => !userRoles.Select(u => u.Id).Contains(r.Id))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: I was hoping to see someone doing the same thing in a more complicated way to get more understanding. thx. I appreciate it.